# Tell Tale Signs of Bot Activity in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My client is having a number of contact enquiries which seem a little 'dodgy'. I am looking at browsers and networks in Google Analytics for any signs of bot activity. Are there any other dimensions which alude to bot activity?

Comment: You **have** to provide more deep details about issue, we can't read your minds

Comment: When it comes to contact forms there are a few techniques that work well:   1.  Add hidden fields that must remain blank, bots tend to fill out everything (even hidden stuff).  2.  Add captcha.    3.  Don't allow `<a href` or `[url` in the message.   Do those and you only get stuff submitted by real people.    My free, open-source contact form implements all of them: https://ostermiller.org/contactform/    I don't think there is anything in GA that can help you determine if submissions are from bots after the fact.

Comment: It may help to install Piwik somewhere on a PC so that you can use to look at customer log files. Any older PC will do as long as it is reasonably fast - especially in disk I/O. It does not have to be rocket fast. Just fast enough to give answers in a reasonable amount of time. I can buy one plenty fast and reliable used for $50 at our local store. I always recommend that people do not look at GA alone. This may help to understand things more. I did this with BT for ad-hoc reports on the fly during conference calls. Cheers!!